# Ubuntu 14 server Unable to ping host

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Can anybody please help me with this:
I just got ssh access to newly set up ubuntu 14 LTS server, however I am not able to install any packages on it. e.g. when I tried to download redis using wget http://download.redis.io/releases/A-WORKING-RELEASE-NUMBER I got message saying failed to resovle host download.redis.io

similarly if I try to do `ping www.google.com` I get error message: "unknown host www.google.com"

What could be the problem?

Comment: check DNS settings in your Ubuntu box.

Comment: check your nameserver settings in '/etc/resolv.conf'. there should be an entry like 'nameserver 8.8.8.8'

Comment: @deagh my /etc/resolv.conf is empty except couple of commented lines there is nothing in it

Comment: Simply check your DNS and internet settings, try resetting your network connection and maybe you need to restart your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve hostnames you have to add a nameserver to your `/etc/resolv.conf` ex:

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: ok I will try adding nameserver details to see if that helps, thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks @deagh
along with namerserer entry I had to add following entries to resolv.conf
domain mydomain.com
search mydomain.com